# Continuous date and time to a different date with same time in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a 40,000 long stack of continuous hydrological data that was reset in the middle of continuous recording while in the field. The result is that it messed up the date and now the two dates don't align. Anyone know if there is a way to change the date of the following data based on the time output? Thanks in advance.

Attached is a photo showing the situation. Recordings from 2011 reset on 1/28/2011 and I want all of the 1/2/2004 fields and beyond to roll over continuously from the 1/28/2011.

[image]

Comment: So the first "1/2/2004" should be "1/29/2011" (12:33:09 AM))?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the very delayed reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the empty column do this thing:

1. For the invalid dates, if the first invalid date is for example in cell `A300` then the formula must be: `=A300+2583`
2. Copy and paste the formula to the next cell down.
3. Select both cells and double click the little dot in the right-down corner of the selection box and it will fill-down the column.
4. Verify that the formula is working checking some random dates.
5. For the valid dates use the formula: `=A2+0`
6. Copy and paste the formula to the next cell down.
7. Select both cells and double click the little dot in the right-down corner of the selection box. It will fill down the column up to the empty cell that you show in your picture.
8. Select the column, right-click and Copy. Right click and go to Special paste, choose values and OK.

Comment: Typo!!!. Corrected

Comment: This worked really well! Thanks for the input and sorry about my delayed reply. I didn't realize there was a response posted. I did have to adjust the values to make it fit exactly. Thank you!